# How to use copy if cqlsh python process takes too much memory

Tags: python, cassandra

Hi I have system with memory 2GB running cassandra. I am using cqlsh to copy a table data to text file. The cqlsh process keeps consuming more and more memory until OOM killer kills the process. I checked this from dmesg log.

> [2432084.824459] Out of memory: Kill process 30688 (python) score 363 or sacrifice child
>   [2432084.824506] Killed process 30688 (python) total-vm:1193556kB, anon-rss:744500kB, file-rss:448kB

On the cqlsh I get

> Child process 30685 died with exit code -9

How to get the text file output which I would get from COPY TO.

**UPDATE**

This or how to copy data of a single instance to another one already having some data ie merge data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2Gb of RAM is very small. And depending on the size of the dataset you want to export, it may be normal to OOM quickly.

> how to copy data of a single instance to another one already having some data ie merge data.

**cassandra-loader**/**cassandra-unloader** is your friend. Have a look here: https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

Comment: The main java process doesnt use more than 1 GB and works fine. I think the python program is poorly written. It should be used only for smaller tables mine is around 50k rows, even then it doesnt work. I will give this a try.

Comment: Hi I tried cassandra unloader but it gives "Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 8589934592 bytes for committing reserved memory." Why does it want to allocate 8 GB ?

Comment: Had to modify Xmx and Xms and compile. Thanks.